# A program that prompts the user to enter a number, and then checks whether the number is divisible by 7 and 11, or either 7 or 11

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators, comparison-operators

```
//TASK 5 PART 1

//Request input from user
let x   = Number(prompt("Enter a number:"));

// using if...else if
if      (x % 7 === 0 && 
         x % 11 === 0) {
         console.log
        (x + " is divisible by 7 and 11");
}

else if (x % 7 === 0 || 
         x % 11 === 0) {
         console.log
        (x + " is divisible by either 7 or 11");
}

else                   {
         console.log
        (x + " is divisible by neither 7 or 11");
}
```

I am very new to JavaScript, and so I am here to ask for help on how to make my code more efficient, using less lines of code, perhaps a method better suited for this program, improve readability or if anybody spots any errors. I am always keen on receiving constructive criticism on where to improve.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Hint: `(x % 7 === 0) + (x % 11 === 0)`. Another hint: `[ "neither", "either", "both" ]`.

Comment: `!(x % 7)` is shorter and equivalent

Comment: Here's another trick: `n = ((0 + !(x % 11)) << 1) + !(x % 7)`. Here `n` will be 0 if divisible by neither, 1 if divisible by only 7, 2 if divisible by only 11, and 3 if divisible by both.

Answer (score 0):

`(x % 7 == 0) && (x % 11 == 0) ? "both" : (x % 7 == 0) || (x % 11 == 0) ? "either" : "neither"`

Here I have used the nested ternary operator, to do the solution in one line.

The syntax is:
`let result = condition ? value1 : value2;`

The condition is evaluated: if it’s truthy then `value1` is returned, otherwise – `value2`.

To know more please refer to this [article.](https://javascript.info/ifelse#conditional-operator)

In my expierince first get comfortable with the basics first, then look to enhance your knowledge of advanced concept of Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it like this.

```
const x = Number(prompt('Number:'));
const d7 = !(x % 7), d11 = !(x % 11);
const result = (d7 && d11) ? 'both 7 and 11' :
               (d7 || d11) ? 'either 7 or 11' :
                             'neither 7 nor 11';
console.log(`${x} is divisible by ${result}`);
```